# Difference between relative path and using $ORIGIN as RPATH

Tags: gcc

Consider the two commands below for building a simple executable

```
$ gcc -g -Wall -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'/sharedLibDir -o prog main.c ./sharedLibDir/libdemo.so

$ gcc -g -Wall -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,./sharedLibDir -o prog main.c ./sharedLibDir/libdemo.so
```

Clearly, one uses a local directory as the RPATH, the other uses $ORIGIN.  I cannot see what the difference is between these two (apart from the value of RPATH and RUNPATH in the binary); both allow the executable to be moved around and, provided it has a parallel directory named sharedLibDir, it runs.

What is the point of $ORIGIN?  Does it have some additional functionality that I have missed?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your use `$ORIGIN`, the lookup is relative to the directory that contains the executable. If you specifiy a relative directory, it's relative to *the current working directory*, which is hardly ever what you want.

Comment: Thanks; I wasn't aware that there was an "install" location as such - I'll look that up shortly.

Comment: The install location is just the directory that contains the executable. Sorry for having confused you, I'll reword my answer.

Comment: So when will the current working directory ever not be the directory containing the executable??

Comment: Well, if you open a terminal and run `ls`, the current working directory will be `/home/Wad`, but the directory containing the `ls` executable is `/bin`.

Comment: What about when symlinks are involved? Is it still the directory of the executable, or is the directory of the symlink?